# Troubleshooting passing data to form (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

What am I doing wrong with passing data to a form?

The routing is all good, the view is initializing, but something in the form is bombing out.

**User Controller:**

```
public function show()
{
 $user = Auth::user();
 return view('showprofile')->with('thisUser', $user); 
}
```

**Form:**

```
<h1>{{ $thisUser->name }} </h1>
```

**Error:**

```
ErrorException in 5404eb375e4ed4f330e070a1642c598527ff029d.php line 9:
Undefined variable: thisUser (View: ....\resources\views\showprofile.blade.php)
```

SOURCE: YouTube Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Qzi1yOoLBQ around the 10 minute mark.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand that you want to pass a variable to view but you are using `with`. `with` is purposely to create `flash session variable` instead of variable to view.

Below is how to pass variable to your view

```
public function show()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $data = ['thisUser' => $user];
    return view('showprofile', $data); 
}
```

in blade file

```
<h1>{{ $thisUser->name }} </h1>
```

Comment: You may be right... there is something about the session involved... but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: @Maxcot are you still getting the same error on `Undefined variable` ?

Comment: Yes I am... It's a very puzzling problem

Answer (score 2):

What you can actually do is just:

```
return view('showprofile', ['thisUser' => Auth::user()]);
```

And you can retrieve this via your blade:

```
<h1>{{ $thisUser->name }} </h1>
```

You do not need the intermediate variable if you are not using this anywhere. That is the beauty of Laravel right?!

Comment: Thanks, that is short and sweet - exactly what I'm looking for... but I still get the blade/view error. `Undefined variable: thisUser`

Comment: maybe you have problem with your routes, in L5 you must have the middleware as "web" to get the proper sessions. Please accept if this is correct. Thanks!


@Maxcot

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'] ], function () {
    //your routes
});

Answer (score 1):

In your blade, you used

```
<h1>{{ $thisUser->name }} </h1>
```

As I know you need to change your return variable with the same name.

```
return view('showprofile')->with('thisUser', $thisUser);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: does your query return proper values? check it and make sure it returns json objects with `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

All of these examples are assuming you are logged in. `Auth::user()` will return `null` instead of a User model in the event you aren't logged in.

In your blade, you can always do:

```
Your name is {{ ($currentUser ? $currentUser->name : null) }}!
```

**Alternatively,** if you don't want to do logic checking in your blade files, you could always do this to return an empty User model, so that way your references still work.

```
return view('blade-file', ['currentUser' => Auth::user() ?: new \App\User]);
```

(of course assuming your user model is \App\User -- replace as needed).

Example output below (both when not logged in):

```
>>> $user = Auth::user()
>>> $user->first_name
PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1
>>> 

>>> $user = Auth::user() ?: new \App\User
=> App\User {#765}
>>> $user->first_name
=> null
```

Now if I login and use the same logic above that returned null instead of an error, it works:

```
>>> Auth::loginUsingId(2)
>>> $user = Auth::user() ?: new \App\User
>>> $user->first_name
=> "Austin"
```

Comment: Yes I am logged in. It's not an authentication problem... I'm sure it's a "passing data to the view" problem. Even with your reommendation `return view('blade-file', ['currentUser' => Auth::user() ?: new \App\User]);` I have exactly the same error.

Comment: In your controller before the `view()`, try doing `print_r(Auth::user()->toArray());` to check the output of that, to definitely 1) verify that you're logged in.

If that fails, add this to the top of your blade to view what is *really* coming into the blade:

`{{ dd(get_defined_vars()['__data']) }}`

Comment: I put `print_r(Auth::user()->toArray());` into the top of the blade, and it shows the details of the logged in user, which is exactly as I expect it should. The minute I add in a `{{ $thisUser }}` I get the error.

Comment: Interesting.. what's your exact `view()` line? Worst case, you could always {{ Auth::user()->name }} in the blade.. but not the best/easiest approach.

Do you see the variable inside the `dd()` command I put above? And it contains the Auth data?

Comment: My exact view line is `return view('editUser', ['thisUser' => Auth::user()]);` and when I put a `{{ dd(get_defined_vars()['__data']) }}` at the start of the blade, I get `array:4 [▼
  "__env" => Factory {#171 ▶}
  "app" => Application {#3 ▶}
  "errors" => ViewErrorBag {#164 ▶}
  "currentUser" => null
]`

Comment: SOLVED: The problem was my routes. I got myself all confused by the different (RESTful) methods in my controller, and my routes. The flow of logic that I thought I was following, was not the chain of logic my app was following.